# Why doesn't my Perl program output anything to my file?

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm trying to write in file *~/.log* but file is remaining empty.
I don't know why this is happening, everything seems fine.

My system is Ubuntu 9.10amd64, Perl 5.10.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# vim:set filetype=perl:

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::Simple qw||;
use Net::SMTP;

# Only because log file
$| = 1;

my $match_string = "... some text to match ..." ;
my $content;

my @mails = ('mejl1@provider1.com',
        'mejl2@provider2.com',
        );
my $data = <<END;

... Subject text ...

END

open(my $log, ">>","$ENV{HOME}/.log")
or die "Couldn't open log file";

sub get( $ ) {
    my $content_ref = shift;

    print {$log} "get: Error: $!\n"
        until ( ${$content_ref}
                = LWP::Simple::get("www.somesite.com/index.html") );
}


my $check_num = 0;
get( \$content );
while ( index($content, $match_string) != -1) {
    print {$log} "Check number $check_num\n"
        or die "Couldn't write in log file";
# This is printed
#    print "Check number $check_num: $ENV{HOME}/.log\n";
    $check_num++;
    get( \$content );
    sleep 60*30;
}


my $server = "smtp.my_provider.org";
my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($server)
    or print {$log} "smtp: Couldn't connect on $server\n";

$smtp->mail('my_mail@my_provider.org')
    or print {$log} "smtp: Error in mail\n";
$smtp->bcc(@mails)
    or print {$log} "smtp: Error in bcc\n";

$smtp->data();

$smtp->datasend($data)
    or print {$log} "smtp: Error when sending data\n";
$smtp->dataend;

$smtp->quit();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you're not patient enough? I see the script waits 3 minutes before exiting.

Note that `$|` works only for the *currently selected filehandle*, which means `STDOUT` here.

You can set it for any filehandle in the old school, complex way:

```
{
    my $old = select $log;
    $| = 1;
    select $old;
}
```

or, if your filehandle is descending from a particular class -- and it's possible autovivified handles belong to this class -- then you can use the `autoflush` method instead, which is a lot easier for you, but does the same thing under the hood:

```
$log->autoflush(1);   # untested
```

Let's hope the latter works.

See [IO::Handle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3A%3AHandle) and [FileHandle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FileHandle) for `autoflush` -- they're related, but I'm unsure which applies here.

Comment: I think you mean it waits 30 minutes. 60*30.

Answer (score 7):

You need to debug each step of your script. You have:

```
print {$log} "get: Error: $!\n"
    until ( ${$content_ref}
            = LWP::Simple::get("www.somesite.com/index.html") );
```

Although you probably changed the URL for your question, as written `get` is probably returning undef. I'm not sure why you are using `until` there. Do you want to run that forever until a site comes online? Check the return values of everything to see what's going on.

I'd reduce most of that part of your script to simply:

```
 while( 1 ) {
      my $data = LWP::Simple::get("http://www.somesite.com/index.html");
      print "got [$data]\n";

      if( substr( ... ) > -1 ) { sleep 1800; next }

      .... do error stuff here ...
      }
```

However, instead of sleeping for 30 minutes, just run the script every 30 minutes from cron. That way you get rid of the looping:

```
 my $data = LWP::Simple::get("http://www.somesite.com/index.html");
 print "got [$data]\n";

 exit if( substr( ... ) > -1 );

 .... do error stuff here ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you present only writes to the log files if anything goes wrong or if $match_string is in $content. Could it be that everything is working fine but there is no match, so the empty log file is exactly what you should be expecting?

Answer (score 1):

try to make it simple first

```
open(my $log, ">>","~/.log")
or die "Couldn't open log file";
print $log "smtp: Error in mail\n";
close  $log
```

does this works ?

Comment: yes, it does. It was just the problem with flushing the buffers. I didn't selected the file handle before setting $| variable.